# ExpressJS post route is not working and returning an error

Tags: node.js, express, post, mean-stack

I am working on a Mean stack application, I have defined an expressjs backend post route to store some data on server, but its not working and returning an error message which is provided for handling errors 'An error occurred in form api'.
[image]

```
router.post('/userform', function (req, res, next) {
    var form = new Form({
        controlType: req.body.controlType,
        label: req.body.label,
        required:req.body.required ,        
        placeholder: req.body.placeholder,
        options: req.body.options
    });
    form.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred in form api',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Form created',
            obj: result
        });
    });
});
```

Its the mongoose schema that I am using:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var formSchema = new Schema({    
    controlType: {type: String, required: true},   
    label: {type: String, required: true},
    required: {type: Boolean}, 
    placeholder: {type: String},   
    options: [String],    //to store options for select or radio input
} ,  {collection: 'inputForm'});

formSchema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Form', formSchema);
```

It is the app.js file:

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Get our API routes
const api = require('./routes/api');
const formApi = require('./routes/form');


const app = express();
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/test-mean');

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

//to avoid cross origin requests errors
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});


// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/form', formApi);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: What is the complete error,you are getting can you post here `err` value?

Comment: error screen shot is attached to question. @abdulbarik

Comment: Can you print your `req.body` I think something is undefined and your validator throwing error

Comment: Make sure put your body-parser configuration above all. Routes

Comment: I printed req.body, it is undefined @abdulbarik

Comment: But I don't know why it is undefined.

Comment: Can you post your app.js file code?

Comment: I have edited app.js file code in my question, sorry for late reply @abdulbarik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159026/discussion-between-waleed-shahzaib-and-abdulbarik).

Comment: I printed req.body, it contains data.

Comment: But I dont know why it is not running successfully and giving error.

Comment: I have given answer with updated `app.js` file, Hope that will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add your body-parser code above all router

```
// Get dependencies
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Parsers for POST data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Get our API routes
const api = require('./routes/api');
const formApi = require('./routes/form');


const app = express();
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/test-mean');


// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

//to avoid cross origin requests errors
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});


// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/form', formApi);

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: I applied this but its not working, still giving the error.

Comment: you are sending the value with form input? if yes then please make  `extended: true`

Comment: Yes I am using form, I have already tried extended: true but its not working.

Comment: It's debugging stuff. can you comment your `res.setHeader` code in middle-ware and then try again.

Comment: By commenting res.setHeader code its giving this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/form/userform. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Please help @abdulbarik

Comment: just comment only `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: It gives this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/form/userform. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: I expanded the error message, I think its kind of mongoose field validation error, as the error message shows: message:"Path `controlType` is required."
name:"ValidatorError"
path:"controlType"
properties:{type: "required", message: "Path `{PATH}` is required.", path: "controlType"}
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: mongoose validation will gives this error when the value of those properties is undefined. I saw this message yesterday so that I asked you to print `req.body` and that was undefined. debugg your code you can get it done.